# Bibinomial coefficient integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For integers $n \ge k \ge 0$ we define the *bibinomial coefficient*.   $\left( \binom{n}{k} \right)$ by
$$ \left( \binom{n}{k} \right) = \frac{n!!}{k!!(n-k)!!} .$$
What are all pairs $(n,k)$ of integers with $n \ge k \ge 0$ such that the corresponding bibinomial coefficient is an integer?

(Note: The double factorial $n!!$ is defined to be the product of all even positive integers up to $n$ if $n$ is even and the product of all odd positive integers up to $n$ if $n$ is odd. So e.g. $0!! = 1$, $4!! = 2 \cdot 4 = 8$, and $7!! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 105$.)

The question is from a [European math competition](http://www.memo2014.de/images/MATERIAL/eng_all_final.pdf), which is already over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
Use that
$$
n!! = 2^kk!
$$
when $n=2k$ and that
$$
n!! = \frac{n!}{2^k k!}
$$
when $n=2k+1$.